# Use soundcloud embed to create embed code from the command line for private sounds

Tags: soundcloud, oembed

I understand that it's possible to use oembed to get embed code for private files, but I'm running into "403 forbidden" when I try it.

```
http://soundcloud.com/albert-albala-1/audio-recording-on-monday/s-VzgUg
```

is accessible in a browser, but

```
curl -iL http://soundcloud.com/oembed?url=http%3A//soundcloud.com/albert-albala-1/audio-recording-on-monday/s-VzgUg&format=json&auto_play=false
```

yields a HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden error. The same call with a public sound works fine:

```
curl -iL http://soundcloud.com/oembed?url=http%3A//soundcloud.com/osmconcerts/rosemarie-landryv2&format=json&auto_play=false
```

Related question: [Rendering SoundCloud widget for a private track using PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779601/rendering-soundcloud-widget-for-a-private-track-using-php-api), although that one uses PHP. I'm trying to get this to work on the command line.

Comment: Hey alberto, I'll pass this on to our back end team.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to embed private tracks using a secret token **if the track's settings allow embedding**.

Embedding is allowed by default, but if you're receiving a 403 with a valid secret token, you've probably disallowed public embedding for the track.

You can enable this through the web UI on your track's edit page under `Settings -> Advanced -> Widget Settings -> Click to enable -> For everybody`:

[image: Widget disabled — click to enable]

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem myself, and the track/sound settings have changed layout/structure since [pje's answer from 30/09/2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103324/869982).

Currently, under Permissions, you need to make sure that 'Display Embed code' is turned on - despite the fact that you may not want this to happen! Doing so should mean a 200 status code is returned along with the embed metadata.

Essentially what this is doing is allowing the track to be publicly embedded on other sites (despite the track being private in terms of not being listed on the main account page).